# Swiftでタブ移動をコードで行った場合に検知する方法はありますか？

Tags: swift, ios, swift5

複数のViewControllerとタブバーを持ったiOSアプリを作成しています。
その中で「最初のタブに戻った場合に所定の処理を実行」というのをやりたいのですが、Swiftコードでタブ移動した場合に検知する方法がわからず困っています。
タブバーのアイコンをタップした場合の検知は
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33837475/detect-when-a-tab-bar-item-is-pressed
こちらのコードを参考にして検知できるようになったのですが、他のViewControllerから
`self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex = 0`
のような形で遷移している処理があり、そちらで移動した場合は上記のURLで書いたコードは反応してくれませんでした。
コードで遷移させたことを遷移先（最初のタブのViewController）の方で検知する方法はあるのでしょうか。
お知恵を拝借できましたら幸甚です。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`selectedIndex`に自分で代入しているのならタイミングはわかっているので、代入の前か後で自分でなんらかの通知を送るか、下記のように自分でデリゲートメソッドを呼ぶと簡単です。

```
tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0
if let selectedViewController = tabBarController.selectedViewController {
    tabBarController.delegate?.tabBarController?(tabBarController, didSelect: selectedViewController)
}
```

ライブラリなどの自分が手を出せない部分で呼ばれているなら、下記のようにKVOを用いて`selectedIndex`または`selectedViewController`を監視する方法もあります。

```
kvoToken = tabBarController?.observe(\.selectedIndex, options: [.new]) { (tabBarController, change) in
    if let selectedIndex = change.newValue {
        print(selectedIndex)
    }
}
```

```
kvoToken = tabBarController?.observe(\.selectedViewController, options: [.new]) { (tabBarController, change) in
    if let newValue = change.newValue,
        let viewController = newValue,
        let viewControllers = tabBarController.viewControllers,
        let selectedIndex = viewControllers.firstIndex(of: viewController) {
        print(selectedIndex)
    }
}
```

この２つの方法には違いがあり、`selectedIndex`を監視した場合は代入したときだけ（タブバーをタップしたときには呼ばれない）、`selectedViewController`の場合はどちらのときでも呼ばれます。

あとはUITabBarControllerを継承して`selectedIndex`に`didSet`を設定するというのも考えられます。

Comment: 教えて頂いた方法で解決できました！
ありがとうございました。